# ISO 8583 message implementation in LoadRunner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, iso8583

Any idea how we can implement ISO 8583 messages in LoadRunner??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a string.

Use your string programming skills in the language of your virtual user (JavaScript, C, C#, Java, ....) to construct your bitmask, then use the transport mechanism to send the message to the next upstream host.

If you require a library, then consider the available options for C, VB, C#, Java, or Javascript to incorporate into your template virtual user.